# Encourage page breaks between items, not within

Tags: lists, page-breaking, enumitem

I have a document with several lists within which I don't want a page break.  In the following document:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[totalheight=2in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item A top level item
    \begin{itemize}
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
    \end{itemize}
    %\newpage
    \item Another top level item
    \begin{itemize}
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

a break occurs in the middle of the second list.  I would like to break automatically at the location of the `\newpage`, even if it means a less optimal break.  Is there a way to prefer breaks between items instead of within an item?

I tried `\usepackage{enumitem} \setlist{midpenalty=5000}`, but this moves the break to just after "Another top level item".  I can get what I'm looking for by enclosing `Another top level item...\end{itemize}` within a `\parbox[t]{\textwidth}`, but that seems heavy handed.  Is there a better way?

It appears that https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76495/107497 would provide a (complicated) way to automatically wrap all items within a minipage, but I was hoping for something simpler.  This does appear to be the same idea as [ConTeXt: Page break preference between nested itemize environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/454806/107497), but that is using ConTeXt.

Comment: `\pagebreak[3]` is the recomended solution, but it doesn.t work very often.  `\vfil\pagebreak[3]` works, but might leave a large gap.

Comment: Additional experiments show that you might as well use `\needspace{3cm}` (needspace package).  The length needed is determined by trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to calculate the space needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\rule{1em}{30\baselineskip}

\begin{itemize}
    \item A top level item
    \begin{itemize}
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
    \end{itemize}
    \setbox0=\vbox{\leftskip\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname
    \item Another top level item
    \begin{itemize}
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
    \end{itemize}}
    \needspace{\ht0}
    \unvbox0
\end{itemize}

\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: But if I'm going to box it up anyway, then I can equally put it into a parbox.  This still requires that I give special treatment to such an item.

Comment: Sad but true.  The question is how big does it have to be before you are willing to split it?

Comment: The 3cm that you mentioned might turn out to be enough, so that needspace would be sufficient.  The catch would be to issue `\needspace{3cm}` before the `\item` that comes before the list.  I'm leaning more and more toward defining an environment `{itemwithlist}` as the best solution.

Comment: To answer your question, lets say that the 6 lines of text is the biggest that we have to worry about.

Comment: That would be `\dimexpr 6\baselineskip+6\itemsep`.

Comment: So I would still need `\needspace{\dimexpr 6\baselineskip+6\itemsep}` at the beginning of `Another top level item`.  Or automatically put that at the beginning of every item, but that could cause a premature page break if the subsequent itemize was short enough.

Comment: You *could* use a `\parbox`, as you said.  Every `\item` starts with a `\par` and it is almost imposislbe to prevent a page break at a `\par`.

Answer (score 0):

I am pressed for time so haven't got time to test, therefore specifically not producing as MWE, -- but if you are talking about encouraging rather than preventing I think you could do something like this with penalties (adapted from one of my list formats so includes other stuff and a specific numbering format I use)

with enumitem package https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem

```
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{6}
\setlist[mylist,1]{label=\Alph*.,ref=\Alph*,itemsep=6pt}
\setlist[mylist,2]{label=\Alph{mylisti}\arabic*.,ref=\Alph{mylisti}\arabic*,itemsep=3pt, beginpenalty=5000}
\setlist[mylist,3]{label=\alph*.,ref=\Alph{mylisti}\arabic{mylistii}.\alph*,itemsep=1pt, beginpenalty=5000}
\setlist[mylist,4]{label=(\arabic*),ref=\Alph{mylisti}\arabic{mylistii}.\alph{mylistiii}(\arabic*),itemsep=1pt, beginpenalty=5000}
\setlist[mylist,5]{label=(\alph*),ref=\Alph{mylisti}\arabic{mylistii}.\alph{mylistiii}(\arabic{mylistiv}\alph*),itemsep=1pt, beginpenalty=5000}
\setlist[mylist,6]{label=(\roman*),ref=\Alph{mylisti}\arabic{mylistii}.\alph{mylistiii}(\arabic{mylistiv}\alph{mylistv}-\roman*),itemsep=1pt, beginpenalty=5000}
\setlist[mylist]{align=left, parsep=3pt, topsep=1pt, itemindent=!, leftmargin=*}
```

I'll come back and revise this pending other responses

Comment: I had tried midpenalty in my original approach.  beginpenalty doesn't seem to affect the page breaking of the given text.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone ahead and wrapped the offending item in an environment:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[totalheight=2in]{geometry}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{unbreakableitem}{o}{%
 \IfValueTF{#1}{\item[#1]}{\item}%
 \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
}{%
 \end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item A top level item
    \begin{itemize}
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{unbreakableitem}
    Another top level item
    \begin{itemize}
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
        \item A second level item
    \end{itemize}
    \end{unbreakableitem}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I suppose a better solution may be to automatically wrap all items in such an environment.  But it seems like I would need a boolean to track if I'm already in an item (and the next `\item` needs to `\end{minipage}` first) or if it's the first such item.