preventing items in an enumerate environment from being split across pages while also ensuring adequate spacing in latex?
i’m working on worksheets for my physics class in latex, and i'm using the enumerate environment to list problems for students. after each problem, i need to provide enough space (e.g., 2 inches) for students to work out the problems. additionally, i want to ensure that no item in the list gets split across pages.
i’ve tried various combinations of \needspace, \vspace, and enumitem options, but i can’t seem to solve both issues at once:

preventing items from splitting across pages.
providing enough vertical space for students to work on each problem.

currently, latex splits items across pages (e.g., one part of a problem at the bottom of one page, and the rest at the top of the next page), and sometimes the space provided for students isn't enough. i’d like to:

ensure the entire problem (plus the space for students) moves to the next page if there’s not enough space.
add a configurable space (e.g., 2 inches) after each problem for students to work.

MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{needspace}

% redefine enumerate to reserve space and prevent splitting
\setlist[enumerate]{
    before=\Needspace{5\baselineskip}, % ensure enough space for problem text + work area
    itemsep=2.25in, % add space for students to work
    topsep=0in
}

\begin{document}
    
    \section*{Physics Worksheet}
    
    At the end of this worksheet you should be able to:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Solve for the momentum of an object.
        \item Apply the conservation of momentum.
    \end{itemize}
    
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item A bug is flying east through the air along a road. What is the bug’s momentum?
        
        \item A car is traveling west along this same road. What is the car’s momentum?
        
        \item You want to close a door but you don’t want to get up. Should you throw a ball or a wad of clay? This is a very very wordy problem that has a lot of extra information in it and would not work without knowing the information so it really is necessary and i would like it to all appear without being broken across this page like it currently is. Do you see it happening? It is about to happen right now?
        
        \item An empty wagon is rolling past you. What happens if you drop a heavy bag into it?
    \end{enumerate}
    
\end{document}



This is similar to an issue I had: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/707960/107497.  You can try playing around with the penalties that enumitem mentions, but I ended up needing to wrap my big items in a minipage.  Do either of those approaches work for you?
